# SharedPreference Flush or clear not working

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

So this is in my first.java

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefss", getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
preferences.getString(currentPlace, "");
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("CurrentPlace", currentPlace);
editor.commit();
```

This is in my second.java

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefss",  getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);    
String curlocation;
curlocation = preferences.getString("CurrentPlace","");
```

say the first class gives the output as aaa the first time now when i go back and redo the process i get aaaaaa this time, the string gets appended. any idea how i could avoid this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preferences.clear()` after `SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();`

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefss", getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
 editor.clear();
 editor.putString("CurrentPlace", currentPlace);
 editor.commit();
```

Comment: im getting this -- > The method clear() is undefined for the type SharedPreferences

Comment: `SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefss", getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);`
`SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit(); editor.clear(); editor.putString("CurrentPlace", currentPlace);
 editor.commit();` Still i get the appended values

Comment: first time i get 1112 and the second time i get 11121112. this is how the current code works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefss", getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
//preferences.getString(currentPlace, "");    // Remove this line
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("CurrentPlace", currentPlace);
editor.commit();
```